# Plotting data from a table in R

Tags: r, csv

new to using "R". I'm plotting air quality data. I've currently got a table I'm pulling from a file I've designated "air" that looks like so:

```
Ozone   Radiation
   3        4
   7        5
   8        3
```

The following is my code, but when I ask R to make a scatter plot of it I get this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x,y,xlabel,ylabel,log) : 'x' and 
'y' lengths differ calls: etc...
```

This is my code

```
air<- read.table("air")

Ozone <- air[1]
Radiation <- air[2]
plot(Ozone,Radiation)
```

I really want to just plot these two data against each other(preferably in a scatter plot). I know this is an elementary question, but thanks for the attention.

Comment: Both `air[1]` and `air[2]` are data.frame with one column.  You may need `air[[1]]` and `air[[2]]` as vectors  or use the formula method `plot(Ozone ~ Radiation, air)`

Comment: Take a look at what `Ozone` and `Radiation` look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code with `ggplot` will give the plot below.

```
df <- data.frame(
       Ozone = c(3L, 7L, 8L),
   Radiation = c(4L, 5L, 3L)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Ozone, y = Radiation)) + geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3)
```

[image]